# UIDatePicker Not storing time in core data

Tags: xcode, core-data

I am using a UIDatepicker with only "Time", I save the time in a NSDate object type, however when I try to store the Object in core data I get an error saying its not a NSDate type...

```
 tt = [pickerTime date]; 

[myObject setValue:tt forKey:@"time"];
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Hey, a see a mistake here:

```
tt = [pickerTime date];
```

tt's type is either an NSDate, or...  You have to declare what tt is:

```
NSDate *tt = [pickerTime date];
```

Make sure that your using a date field in IB.